# How to test if a view is in the top layer?

Tags: android, z-order

I have a View, I want to know if there is a way to test if the view is in the top layer or it has the biggest z-value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such property/value like **z-index** in android except the order in which you add your views in a `FrameLayout`. However, you may do the following to verify if the view itself is the parent or not:

```
if(v.getParent() == null){
   //view is parent
}
else{
   //view is not parent
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to test if the view is most close to our eye from the screen, not the farthest. We can see the application as a tree, I think your way gives the root, but I want the leaves.

Comment: @leiwang Check if the children count == 0